# Is the question statement wrong or am I not understanding this?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

The question is: 
If $f(x) = 1 + \int_a^x{(x-t)^nf(t)\,dt},\ f(a) = 1$ Show that $f^{(n)}(a) = n!$

Here are my steps:

\begin{align}
f'(x) &= n\int_a^x{(x-t)^{n-1}f(t)\,dt}\\
f''(x) &= n(n-1)\int_a^x{(x-t)^{n-2}f(t)\,dt}\\
&...\\
f^{(m)}(x) &= \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}\int_a^x{(x-t)^{n-m}f(t)\,dt}
\end{align}

So if $m = n$, $$f^{(n)}(a) = n!\int_a^x{f(t)\,dt}$$
Now plugging in $x = a$ will give us zero!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: we can't help you if you don't write how you solved the problem

Comment: I just edited the question, I hope you can help now.

Comment: It is necessary to put the problem statement in the body of the question, but it also is good to have it in the title if it fits. What I mean to say is that all the edits you made below the title were necessary and good, but the original title was fine as it was and you could (I think should) restore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am miscounting, I think there **is** an error in the problem statement.

As long as the power of $x - t$ in the integral is positive,
each application of Leibniz's integral rule
has the same result you showed.
My calculations agree and [so does Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%28%5Cint_a%5Ex+%28x-t%29%5Ek+f%28t%29dt%29%2Fdx).
After taking the derivative $n$ times, you arrive at

$$
f^{(n)}(x) = n! \int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt.
$$

And indeed $f^{(n)}(a) = n! \int_a^a f(t)\,\mathrm dt = 0.$
But if you differentiate one more time, you find that

$$
f^{(n+1)}(x) = n! f(x)
$$
and therefore $f^{(n+1)}(a) = n! f(a) = n!$.

So I suspect that whoever made this problem miscounted the number of applications of the derivative by $1$.
What they should have asked you to prove is that $f^{(n+1)}(a) = n!$,
not that $f^{(n)}(a) = n!$.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting wrong results is you are not applying the derivative rule correctly in the last step. The correct version is

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xg(x,t)dt = g(x,x) + \int_a^x\frac{d}{dx}g(x,t)dt. $$

You not only have to take the derivative of the integrand, but also check out what happens with the boundaries. In your case, this is especially important as they are dependent on $x$. Look up Leibniz's Integral Rule. And this comes up at the last iteration of your steps, because $0^0$ is taken to mean $1$ in your task.

Comment: But it's f(t) not f(x).

Comment: I wrote $f$ to mean any function. In your case, $$f=(x-t)^{n}f(t)$$.

Comment: Just changed it to $g$, so $g(x)=(x-t)^n f(t).$

Comment: I think you might be using $x$ as both an input as well as the variable we're integrating against - this might be clearer with $g(x,t)$

Comment: @George Thanks, I changed $dx$ into $dt$.

Comment: Can you look at the question again after the edit, it's asking for $f^{(n)}(a)$ not $x$?

Comment: The notation $g'$ for a function $g(\cdot,\cdot)$ of two variables is unclear.

Comment: you should use partial derivative

Comment: Fixing the notation $g'$ and applying Leibniz's integral rule carefully as shown here, I get the same results as OP. Wolfram Alpha agrees (see my answer). I don't think the difficulty is due to any mistake by OP in carrying out any of the differentiations.